# PostgreSQL execute statement conditionally by server version

Tags: postgresql

I'm currently writing some installer script that fires SQL files against different database types depending on the system's configuration (the webapplication supports multiple database server like MySQL, MSSQL and PostgreSQL).

One of those types is PostgreSQL. I'm not fluent with it and I would like to know if it's possible to make a statement into a define/populate SQL file that makes an SQL query conditional to a specific PostgreSQL server version.

How to make an SQL statement conditionally in plain PGSQL so that it is only executed in version 9? The command is:

```
ALTER DATABASE dbname SET bytea_output='escape';
```

The version check is to compare the version with `9`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Postgres does have [`version()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-info.html) function, however there is no `major_vesion()`. Assuming that output string always includes version number as `number(s).number(s).number(s)` you could write your own wrapper as:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION major_version() RETURNS smallint
AS $BODY$ 
    SELECT substring(version() from $$(\d+)\.\d+\.\d+$$)::smallint;
$BODY$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

Example:

```
=> Select major_version();
 major_version
---------------
             9
(1 row)
```

However real issue here is that AFAIK you [can't](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html) execute your commands conditionally in "pure" SQL and best what you can do is to write some stored function like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION conditionalInvoke() RETURNS void
AS $BODY$
BEGIN
    IF major_version() = 9 THEN
        ALTER DATABASE postgres SET bytea_output='escape';
    END IF;
    RETURN;
END;
$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I think that you should rather use some scripting language and generate appropriate SQL with it.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. We're acutally using PHP and execute the statement conditionally. I thought it would be easier to do in PGSQL directly so I could reduce the PHP installer script, but well, I think you've answered my question and well, it was a dream of mine :)

Comment: This won't always work: I have `9.1rc1` and `9.2devel` around at the moment. ;-)

Comment: I'm trying to decide what the most stable would be, maybe something like this?: `SELECT substring(version() from $$PostgreSQL (\d+)\.\d+$$);`

Answer (score 4):

Or you could just use

```
select setting from pg_settings where name = 'server_version'
```

Or

```
select setting from pg_settings where name = 'server_version_num'
```

If you need major version only

```
select Substr(setting, 1, 1) from pg_settings where name = 'server_version_num'
```

or

```
select Substr(setting, 1, strpos(setting, '.')-1) from pg_settings where name = 'server_version'
```

if you want it to be compatible with two digit versions.

Comment: +1 for smart use of `server_version` and `server_version_num` [preset options](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-preset.html) :)

Comment: I'm worried about the 'two digit version' you included. Is it not stripping the zeros? what if the version is 91000 (9.10.0), how do you account for that?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could make things dependent on the output of
select version();
(probably you'll have to trim and substring that a bit)

BTW (some) DDL statements may not be issued from within functions; maybe you'll have to escape to shell-programming and here-documents.